# "no basic auth credentials" while building docker file from ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I have below docker file, which is referencing from base image in ECR.( and a lot of lines in the file)

```
FROM XXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/baseImage:3.0.0
```

But while building the image

```
docker build -t test .
```

I'm getting below error at the first line itself:

```
Step 1/2 : from XXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/baseImage:3.0.0
Get https://xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/baseImage/manifests/3.0.0: no basic auth credentials
```

So, how to create an docker file and build a image from the ECR.
`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1` Do, I have to get the username and password from this and pass as argument in dockerfile  and during the build? what is the best practice?

Is there any sample I can refer to?

Comment: You need to run `docker login` (or `$(aws ecr get-login)`) once before you start.  There’s not a code-related change you can make to automate this.